# Regular Expression for not allowing consecutive |!| characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
console.log('aaaa dfdd |!|'.search(/|!|/g));
if(/|!|/g.test("abcd |aaa!|")) alert('true');*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `|` and `!` are special characters in regular expressions, so you need to escape them:

```js
if(/\|\!\|/g.test("abcd |aaa!|")) alert('wrong');
if(/\|\!\|/g.test("abcd |aaa|!|")) alert('correct');
```